# Double spread problem - getting rid of Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

Here is my reducer body code fragment:

```
const newState = {
    ...state,
    programs: {
        ...state.programs,
        ...Object.assign(
            {},
            ...action.payload.map(
                (channelName) =>
                    ({
                        [channelName]: {
                            ...state.programs[channelName],
                            selected: true
                        }
                    })
            )
        )
    }            
}
return newState
```

Is there any chance to get rid of `Object.assign` in this case?

The classical advice to change `Object.assign({}, a)` to `{ ...a }`  does not work in this case, because here we already have `...action.payload.map`, so it would result in `... { ...a }` which makes spread to produce array-like keys of 0,1,2...

Is there any elegant way to transform my code correctly?

Comment: You can spread in a reduce loop, but in this case `Object.assign({}, ...array of objects)` is the elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const action = {
  payload: ['discoveryChannel']
}

const state = {
  programs: {
    cartoonNetwork: {
      description: '',
      when: new Date()
    },
    discoveryChannel: {
      description: '',
      when: new Date()
    }
  }
}

const newState = {
  ...state,
  programs: {
    ...state.programs,
    ...Object.fromEntries(
         action.payload.map(
           channelName => ([
             channelName, {...state.programs[channelName], selected: true}
           ])
         )
       )
  }
}
console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really beautiful. I was wandering near this, but was missing the last step to generate the entry pair by returning it from the map...

Answer (score 4):

Ever heard of `reduce`?

```js
const action = {
  payload: ['discoveryChannel']
}

const state = {
  programs: {
    cartoonNetwork: {
      description: '',
      when: new Date()
    },
    discoveryChannel: {
      description: '',
      when: new Date()
    }
  }
}

const newState = {
  ...state,
  programs: {
    ...state.programs,
    ...action.payload.reduce(
      (acc, channelName) => {
        acc[channelName] = {
          ...state.programs[channelName],
          selected: true
        }

        return acc;
      }, {})
  }
}
console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Now I wonder if reduce is more readable than Object.assign, however many thanks for that.

Comment: @EF If you want to make it more "readable", move the reducer function out of the nested scope.